# Conditional formatting - wrong rows

Tags: vba, conditional-formatting

I would like to create a macro that resets all the condition formatting on a sheet, but for some reason the code ends up pointing to the bottom of the page. From memory, I have add this problem before, which worked fine at home, but the same code did not work at work.

Any suggestions please?

```
Public Function ResetHoursSheet()
    With Worksheets("Hours").Range("$H2:$H2000")
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$D2 = ""A/L"""
        .FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
    End With
End Function
```

After the code runs, the condition formatting show this...

```
=$D1048570 = "A/L"
```

Comment: why are you writing this as a function? A function is meant to return a value, not manipulate cells in a sheet.

Comment: Select the range before adding the CF.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behaviour. It works fine for me whichever range I have selected.

Comment: Using your exact function it works for me (pressing F5 to run) how are you triggering this event? and what version of excel is it

Comment: Teylyn, I tried to write the condition as a formula but kept getting a error, So was not sure what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Tim Williams. Your solution worked. Selecting the range before hand and working with the selection produces the correct result. Thanks. Is there anyway to mark this as solved by you so you get the credit?

Comment: ClintB - Runnng office 2007. Not sure what revision at I cannot find where to look

Comment: Appears to have two solutions to this problem. The first being what Tim Said. https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/895562/the-conditional-formatting-may-be-set-incorrectly-when-you-use-vba-in-excel Its worth noting that I do not have this issue using office 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Worksheets("Hours").Range("$H2:$H2000").ClearFormats
```